# How to search if a dictionary has keys with the same name as elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tabular

I have a list which is:

```
['GBP','EUR','USD',....] #and many more money codes
```

and a dictionary which is like the following:

```
{'GBP': 'Great British Pound', 'EUR': The Euro...} #and many more like this
```

How do i go about seeing if each element is in the dictionary and if it is in the dictionary print the name and the code.

Output should look something like this:

```
Great British Pound (GBP)
The Euro (EUR)
U.S. Doller (USD)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like set intersection might be what you are looking for.

```
l = ['GBP', 'EUR', 'USD']
d = {'GBP': 'Great British Pound', 'EUR': 'The Euro'}

for k in d.keys() & l:
    print(d[k]+" ("+k+")")
```

edit: JuniorCompressor's code does the same thing.

Comment: Try `set(l) & d.keys()`

Comment: d.keys() needs to be a set.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: It doesn't work on 2.7...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'

Comment: Check the tags in the question